# Using multiple tables to show products from a cart page

Tags: php

I've managed to get one stock table to display in the cart page when the user selects an item to purchase but I can't figure out how to get more than one table from different pages to display.
Any help would be appreciated!

```
    <?php
   session_start();
   $cart=$_SESSION["cart"];

   extract($_POST);
   if (IsSet($productid)||IsSet($_SESSION["notempty"])) $empty=false;
   else $empty=true;

   if (!$empty)
   {
      if (IsSet($cart[$productid])) $cart[$productid]+=$quantity;
      else $cart[$productid]=$quantity;
      $_SESSION["notempty"]=true;
   }

   $_SESSION["cart"]=$cart;

   $conn=mysql_connect("","");
   mysql_select_db("webent",$conn);
   mysql_query("CREATE TABLE Stock (stock_ID INT(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                    itemName VARCHAR(50),itemDesc VARCHAR(100),
                                    itemImage VARCHAR(10),itemStock VARCHAR(3),
                                    itemPrice VARCHAR(5))");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">

<head>
   <title>Jus' Books</title>
   <link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

   <div id="masthead">

   </div>

   <div id="navigation">
      <p><a href="index1.php">Home</a>
      <a href="fiction.php">Fiction</a>
      <a href="travel.php">Travel</a>
      <a href="sport.php">Sport</a>
      <a href="arts.php">Arts & Design</a>
      <a href="cart.php">Shopping Cart</a>
      <a href="account.php">Manage Account</a></p>
   </div>

   <div id="content">

      <?php

      if ($empty) echo "<h4>Your shopping cart is empty</h4>";
      else
      {
         echo "<h4>Your shopping cart contains:</h4>";
         $total="";
         foreach ($cart as $id=>$no)
         {
            if ($id!="")
            {
               $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Stock WHERE stock_ID= $id");
               $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
               extract($row);



               if ($itemStock<$no) $no=$itemStock;

               echo "<p>$no units of item $itemName at $itemPrice each</p>";
            }
            $total+=$no*$itemPrice;
         }
         echo "<p>Total to pay: £$total</p>";
      }

      ?>

      <a href="index1.php">Continue Shopping</a>
      <a href="checkout.php">Proceed to Checkout</a>
      <p></p>

   </div>

   <div id="footer">
      <p><a href="index1.php">Home</a> | 
      <a href="fiction.php">Fiction</a> |
      <a href="travel.php">Travel</a> |
      <a href="sport.php">Sport</a> |
      <a href="arts.php">Arts & Design</a> |
      <a href="cart.php">Shopping Cart</a> |
      <a href="account.php">Manage Account</a></p>
   </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

The other tables have the exact same fields but have the name Stock_Travel
Stock_Sport
Stock_Arts

Comment: **WARNING** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to get more than one table from different pages to display

What do you mean by that? If you want to select from different tables, alter the query:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Stock_Travel WHERE stock_ID= $id");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Stock_Sport WHERE stock_ID= $id");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Stock_Arts WHERE stock_ID= $id");
```

I hope this is some kind of homework assignment, since it's full of tiny flaws that wouldn't be nice in a production environment.

As you see, the database layout is far from optimal. Why isn't Travel/Sport/Arts stored in a `Category` field in the Stock table? That way you don't have to alter your query based on the kind of product page you're on.

Furthermore, I wouldn't rely on `extract()`, but that's personal. You definitely will want to escape your queries, or rather use prepared statements.

Comment: It is just for an assignment. I didnt really think the database through as well as I should have. Thanks for your response. I'm giving it a go now :)

Comment: Im getting the following error with the extract line..
"Warning: extract() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cart.php on line 86"